# Cancel Before_Update event of Subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some code in Before_Update event of Subform. Can I Cancel this code when I click on another control in Main form, like a Cmdbutton ? I tried with this, but It's not working:

```
Public CnclEvnt As Boolean

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If CnclEvnt=True Then
Cancel=True
End if
End sub

Private Sub cmdButton1_Click()
CnclEvnt=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The update happens before the click event or any other event like the OnExit of the subform control.

The only method I can see is to always cancel the update and then have a button to actively save the record. However, if you have several records in the subform, this would be very cumbersome.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks for response. I just want to move all Save\Edit\Add buttons outside of subform, because I can't set scrollbar only to Detail section of subform - therefore subform looks strange with scrollbar. And I have Before_Update code for every changes of records, which works fine, but doesn't let me cancel It when I want to click on Save buton outside subform.